# Not all info files are found on Windows

Tags: emacs, info

For some reason Emacs running in Windows 7 only loads the info files installed from Cygwin. If I try to <kbd>C-u C-h i</kbd>`d:/cygwin/usr/local/lib/emacs-24.3/info/dired-x.info` the info file loads and renders ok. The value of `Info-default-directory-list` is

```
("c:/emacs/info/" "d:/cygwin/usr/local/lib/emacs-24.3/info/" "d:/cygwin/usr/info")
```

I've also tried:

```
(push "/usr/local/lib/emacs-24.3/info" Info-default-directory-list)
```

Both adding and removing the trailing slash - but Emacs doesn't find the info files in that directory. What may be the reason?

Comment: Which Emacs is installed?  For example, GNU Emacs 24.3.1.  Your computer could have a different version of GNU Emacs.  Or it could have another Emacs distribution such as XEmacs.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue myself, but it went away when I moved my setup to another laptop.

I can only guess, but I presume it was because I had copies of cygwin and git installed (also added some mingw tools) which were interfering somehow?